# Is there a way to create a document.editable toggle?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I would like to know if it is possible to turn this into a toggle so if you click it and the content is editable, it makes it not editable, same thin flipped.

Here is the code `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post a sample code that you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: I haven’t really tried much, I’m wondering if it’s possible to die something like if content.editable = true document.content.editable=false

Comment: I don’t really know Java that well so I usually come to Stack Overflow when I cans find something out via Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy with a [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Here you go:

```
javascript: document.body.contentEditable = document.body.contentEditable=='false'?'true':'false'; document.designMode=document.designMode=='on'?'off':'on';document.close();alert(document.body.contentEditable + document.designMode);
```

Take off the `alert()` at the end when you're sure it's working like you want.

Answer (score -1):

something like that works for me.

```
    function SWITCH_EDITABLE_BY_ELEMENT(elm) {
      if (elm){
         if (elm.isContentEditable !== true) {
            elm.contentEditable = true;
            return;
      } else {
           elm.contentEditable = false;
           return;   
     }
   }



 var elm=document.getElementById="i_am_lazy"
 SWITCH_EDITABLE_BY_ELEMENT(elm);
```

Comment: Is there a way to put this in one snipped and have it apply to the whole page (HTML tag?) rather than one element?